# Winform Syncfusion ToolStripRadioButton image

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, syncfusion

I am working with Syncfusion in a Winform project.  I am trying to add a ToolStripEx ToolStripRadioButton.  The ToolStripEx is in Ribbon.

I want that the Radio buttons will be images.

My code is:

```
LayoutCoosing.Items.Add(new ToolStripRadioButton()
{ 
    Name = "SingleScreenDividerButton",
    DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image,
    Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("SingleScreenDivider"),
    GroupID = 0,
    Checked = true
});
```

I checked out and the image path is OK.  Why doesn't the RadioButton got the image?

Answer (score 0):

`ToolStripRadioButton` does not support to show image. Because the `ToolStripRadioButton` is derived  from `ToolsStripButton`, so it will avoid the base render to render `RadioButton` appearance and we don’t have any implementation to render the image in it.

But this support will be available in our future releases.